# How do I create a command line application that will force the use of proxies for certain other applications?

Tags: c#, proxy

What I'm basically trying to do is create a command line alternative to [widecap](http://widecap.ru). How I imagine this thing to work:

1. External application calls my command line tool and passes the proxy as an argument
2. The command line tool launches and redirects all web traffic for the application that called it through the proxy that was passed as an argument
3. External application closes the command line tool after it's done

The reason why I don't want to implement the proxy support directly into the external application's code is that I will not always be writing the external applications. I want it to be a separate tool that can be used by anyone.

Any directions/feedback/suggestions/links/ideas that you could give me will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Just to be more clear, I would like to see a code example in C# that demonstrates how I can "hook" on a running process and tunnel all its web traffic through a proxy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not do what are you asking for without decompiling/disassembling the external program and editing its code to do what are you asking for.
Another solution would be to program your C# application to capture the packets of the external application and redirecting them to your proxy server. This will be difficult to achieve but it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in that you want this to be shared between multiple applications. The basic best practices approach would be for each program to have these options:

```
Manual Settings
None (ignore proxy)
System System Settings
Auto Detect
```

From what you are saying it sounds like you want to have a shared setting between many applications that have no relation to each other but not all applications which tends to break the model.

Now for the sake of argument if all these applications are co-workers etc. building a suite of tools under a common development pattern it is possible, however if that isn't the case it would be difficult.

The only way I see this as feasibly working is to utilize a local proxy server which would grab the name of the open application/process and redirect traffic to the system proxy or to the custom proxy setting. This is how Virtual machines function, but there tends to be a constant struggle in these types of programs properly identifying all the related and subprocesses that should be redirected.

Comment: I prefer the external application itself to be ignorant about proxies. It just needs to know how to call the command line tool. I'm pretty sure it's doable though since widecap does it.

Comment: In windows 7 & Vista, UAC directly attempts to prevent this sort of behavior. Perhaps a better choice would be to implement a full proxy server instead of a psuedo-proxy such as the way widecap works. You can get the sourcecode free from many of these open source projects.

Comment: Can you explain why I should create a full proxy server instead of a pseudo-proxy? And if possible give me an example of code from such an open source project?

Answer (score 0):

In windows 7 & Vista, UAC directly attempts to prevent this sort of behavior which is why most proxifiers tend to have issues.

Here are 2 decent alternatives I am aware of (both have the same name):

Free one: http://sourceforge.net/projects/proxifier/ 
Paid one: http://www.proxifier.com/download.htm

I would try the first one since I recall it supporting command line arguments without a lot of hassle. I had problems with the second one listed, but it may fit your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

proxy servers are servers! and listen on specific Port Number(s) if packet send to them can catch them. exist one ambiguity  in your question:

1. Application connect to proxy interface and design Message language between(application know using the proxy).
   in this case your work is writing Proxy Server application.
2. force applications to use proxy interface.(application don't know using interface)

   in this case you can use Network interface upper level driver such as wincap
   to achieve all packet , and in short term write your packet sniffing + firewall tools
   same as cain & able or WireShark and do some filtering on packet target Port numbers
   and do your adequate work
   suggest you to detemine Fast and weak tool way(1) or
   long time working  and sophisticated tools (2).
   Good luck